# Motodev Core Plugins

Tags: android, eclipse, motodev-studio

With the announcement of the Motodev core plugins being included in the AOSP tools (http://developer.motorola.com/tools/motodevcoreplugins/), I have been trying unsuccessfully to get them to work properly in Eclipse.

I have followed the instructions on downloading and installing everything. However, once the projects for the plugins are completely imported into my new workspace, a few of them show build errors. I have tried cleaning the projects, etc. but they still show build errors.

I decided to go ahead and try to install the plugins according to the directions. Once the plugins were installed and I completed the instructions, I see the MOTODEV option up in the menu bar. However, once I go to click on any of the options (i.e. MOTODEV > New > New Android Project), nothing happens. This is the same for every option in the MOTODEV menu.

Has anybody gotten the plugins to build and install correctly in their existing Eclipse setup? If so, am I missing something?

Thanks.

UPDATE: I have also discovered that installing these plugins per the instructions breaks the "Run" button in the toolbar in Eclipse. It simply doesn't do anything for me now. I have to right click the project and do Run As from the context menu. Obviously not a huge issue...but still an annoyance. Also, I noticed this on my OSX setup:

If I click "New -> New Android Project" I notice this error appears in the error log:

Error Tue Oct 02 11:50:32 CDT 2012 Unhandled event loop exception
org.eclipse.e4.core.di.InjectionException: org.eclipse.core.commands.NotHandledException: There is no handler to execute for command com.motorola.studio.android.new.project  at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.MethodRequestor.execute(MethodRequestor.java:63)  at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.invokeUsingClass(InjectorImpl.java:229)  at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.invoke(InjectorImpl.java:210)  at org.eclipse.e4.core.contexts.ContextInjectionFactory.invoke(ContextInjectionFactory.java:131)  at org.eclipse.e4.core.commands.internal.HandlerServiceImpl.executeHandler(HandlerServiceImpl.java:171)  at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.HandledContributionItem.executeItem(HandledContributionItem.java:814)  at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.HandledContributionItem.handleWidgetSelection(HandledContributionItem.java:707)  at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.HandledContributionItem.access$7(HandledContributionItem.java:691)  at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.HandledContributionItem$4.handleEvent(HandledContributionItem.java:630)  at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)  at  org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.MethodRequestor.execute(MethodRequestor.java:56)  ... 37 more

Comment: I found this post: http://community.developer.motorola.com/t5/MOTODEV-Studio-for-Android-Blog/MOTODEV-Studio-4-0-and-the-ADT-20-plugins/ba-p/27710. It suggest to not use MotoDev Studio 4 with older versions of Android

Comment: I see. But what I'm trying to use now is referred to as the "Motodev Core Plugins." I'm not sure if this still applies, as I am using the latest ADT plugins.

Comment: MOTODEV studio 4 is Motodev Core Plugins

Comment: No. Motodev Studio is Motorola's IDE based off Eclipse. Motodev Core Plugins are just that...the core plugins from Studio, but installed in Eclipse classic. Motodev Studio, if I'm not mistaken, did not require one to clone into the repository, build, and install all the plugins. It was its own closed-source customization of Eclipse.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After two days I got MOTODEV Core Plugin to work in Eclipse.
In general follow these directions http://developer.motorola.com/tools/motodevcoreplugins/

1. You need a 100% fresh install of Java EE. If you are on windows stick with 32bit version. I have Juno Java EE installed. This install includes packages that are necessary for MOTODEV to work.

I got it here:
http://download.eclipse.org/eclipse/downloads/eclipse3x.html

2. Next install ADT

ADT https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/

3. Install Sequoyah from the Eclipse Download page, (not what is on MOTODEV's site)

http://download.eclipse.org/sequoyah/updates/2.0/

4.When installing MOTODEV,
Remove MOTODEV packages you don't need like linus, macos and com.motorola.studio.android.wind32.x86_64

5. install Sequoyah again, this time from MOTODEV's specifcations 
   Sequoyah    http://download.eclipse.org/sequoyah/updates/2.1/2.1.1.N20120718-0509

At this point, there should be no errors in your project.

Now to run MOTODEV,
select package com.motorola.studio.android and run as 'Eclipse Application'

Next a window will open that has the MOTODEV menu in the main window.

[image]

Comment: Thank you. I will have to try this. Now, do you know if it will work to add it as a plugin, as the Motodev instructions suggest? That is what I would like to do ideally, so I just have the features as plugins in Eclipse, as opposed to running the project to open up Motodev. Or will your steps do what I just asked?

Comment: i followed the instructions on the site for the plugin

Comment: Ok. I'm on OSX. Do you think I should stick with the 32bit version as well?

Comment: "If you are on windows stick with 32bit version." ...I mean for the Eclipse Java EE

Comment: Sorry dont now much about how mac. However, all android scrips are in 32 bit. so I'd stick with it, unless you get strange bugs and errors

Comment: I got this to work, as far as running it as an Eclipse application. But, it still does not work when I try to install it as a plugin.

Comment: Update: finally got it working. This helped a lot, so thank you.

Comment: I tried this but for some reason it doesn't allow me to debug

Comment: There is a problem with MaxPermsSize that will prevent MOTODEV from running correcltly  on pc. I'm not sure what going on with your install from your comment.

Comment: There is a new build of these plugins available now.  https://kingargyle.github.io/p2/motodev-android/  Use that as a New site in Install Software and you should be able to install without having to build them yourself.

Answer (score 2):

Look at the errors, they provide information about the tools you are missing.
After I've gone through the motodev tutorial, I had to install Web Service Tools, Database Tools (DTP) and Memory Analizer Tool (MAT).
Also, Leoa is right, for people using windows, stick with win32, even if your windows is x64.