# Error when trying to install Motodev Core Plugin

Tags: android, motodev-studio

I was using Motodev Studio before but since that is not possible anymore I need to install Motodev Core Plugin. I followed the guide on the motodev site http://developer.motorola.com/tools/motodevcoreplugins/ and everything went fine until I had to install Motodev Core Plugin. It began to install but after a little time I got this message:

[image]

Then I retried with no luck. Then I restarted Eclipse and imported the projects again but now it can't build the project because of 1924 errors

Does anyone have a clue what to do? I have also tried to follow this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12692865/motodev-core-plugins) with no luck eather. I just wish it would be as easy as before: Download --> install --> finish

:(

Comment: Do you choose the languagepacks folder yourself? It looks a bit weird to me with the backslash before eclipse and then a normal slash afterwards.

Comment: I did choose all 5 or six but I can't remember if there was a language pack among. Yes that does absolutely look wierd.

Comment: That seems to be the error for me, maybe you can create that folder yourself and try to run the installer again?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ran into other problems with installing the Motodev Core Plugins. Although it wasn't the same issue, I would suggest trying the steps listed in the answer here: [Motodev Core Plugins](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12692865/motodev-core-plugins)

Comment: that is also what I am doing, but I have all those errors when building the projects.... How can I get rid of them?

Comment: From what I can see in the error message, it says it could not create a directory. In my experience, this is a permissions issue. I would make sure your user account has full control of that folder. Perhaps you could try running Eclipse as Administrator as well.

Comment: Actually, I just noticed that path is malformed as well. Did you choose that path? For Windows, all slashes should be back slashes. So, the path should read "C:\Program Files\eclipse\LanguagePacks" ...that's probably why it can't create the directory, because the last slash in your error message is a forward slash.

Comment: Hey again. I have followed the guide now and were able to run com.motorola.studio.android and get the MOTODEV menu. Now how do I continue? I need the MOTODEV menu to be there by default. Not only when I run this project. Should I go and install new software as the http://developer.motorola.com/tools/motodevcoreplugins/ instructs or will that just bring the problem back on?

Comment: OK. Now that you have the project able to run, here's what you need to do. Go to Help > Install New Software. Click Add > Local. Choose the project directory where all the Motorola projects are stored that you just ran successfully. In other words, where all the com.motorola folders are from the project, choose the parent directory of those folders. Then, once you click OK make sure you uncheck "Group Items by Category" and select all the MOTODEV plugins. Install and you should be good.

Comment: ohh :( After I did this the MOTODEV menu shows OK. But when I click anything in it nothing happens. And when I go to preferences -> MOTODEV I get this error: Unable to create the selected preference page.
com.motorola.studio.android.preferences.ui.MotodevStudioPreference Any Idea what to do now?

Comment: I had this happen to me. Are you sure you chose the correct directory where all the plugins' project folders are stored? This could differ from the "src" directory of the original git clone. For example, if you copied the projects into your workspace by default, when you install the plugins you have to navigate to that workspace and find the folder with the projects, not the folder where you cloned the git repo. I would try again by going to Help > Install Software > "What's already installed?" > select all MOTODEV, click Uninstall. Then try again.

Comment: I cant find the right folder for it. I have selected C:/Users/UserName/EclipseSetupWorkspace/ When I watch that folder in the file explorer all the project folders is there - but Eclipse doesn't see them :S

Comment: Are you typing in the file path like that, with incorrect (forward) slashes instead of Window's backward slashes? Eclipse will never see it if so.

Comment: I don't type it. I click on local and selects the folder. Then eclipse inserts the path itself. But I also tried with the slashes the other way.

Answer (score 0):

You might have a security issue with creating things in the "Program Files" folder.  Try moving your your eclipse folder to your "My Documents" folder where you have full control and then reinstall the plugin.